# Sum in two group kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui

My kendoGrid have two group and i sum in **groupfooterTempalte**, but it don't know  which group follow.And i don't know post problem to kendo forum :((

Thanks for watch,

**My example**

http://dojo.telerik.com/urojO

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "vung" },
    { field: "cn" },
    { field: "BT",
      groupFooterTemplate: "total: #= sum #",
     aggregates: ["sum"]
    }
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { vung: "v1", cn: "TIN1", BT: 21 },
      { vung: "v1", cn: "TIN1", BT: 17 },
      { vung: "v1", cn: "TIN2", BT: 22 },
      { vung: "v1", cn: "TIN2", BT: 13 },
      { vung: "v2", cn: "PN1", BT: 13 },
      { vung: "v2", cn: "PN1", BT: 15 }
    ],
    group: [{ field: "vung", aggregates: [ { field: "BT", aggregate: "sum" }] },
            { field: "cn", aggregates: [ { field: "BT", aggregate: "sum" }] }]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the scripts as below,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2017.3.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

We also faced the same issue. And its fixed once we updating with latest scripts.